# How to intercept didStartLoad in web view (metro apps)

Tags: windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro

I have been developing iOS and Mac OSX apps since years. So, I was pretty surprised to find no method for Windows 8 Metro WebView to intercept when it starts loading a new page, but only when it finishes loading.

Is there really any workaround for this? I could not find anything both in the docs and on the web...

Thank you very much!

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Window.External.Notify()` method to trigger an event back in your C# or whatnot. You can also use the `Webview.InvokeScript()` to activate scripts from outside the control. You can write a script as a string outside the WebView and use the `WebView.InvokeScript()` with "eval" as the first arg to run that script inside the control.

[ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx)

[This shows how to use both ScriptNotify and InvokeScript](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)